# Sub component when put on static property of Class component returns undefined

Tags: reactjs

Trying to make a `NavBar` component using the compound component pattern, where sub components are placed on the static property of the parent component.

Putting a component on like this `NavBar.ComponentName = Component` so that else where can use it as a child of `NavBar` but cant understand why it always returns undefined in the render method of the components where it used.

The project was bootstrapped using CRA 2.0.

```
// Navbar.js
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'react-jss';

import NavBarRightItem from './NavBarRightItem';
import { navBar } from './styles';

class NavBar extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const { classes, children } = this.props;
    return(
      <div className={classes.nav} >
        { children }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

NavBar.NavBarRight = NavBarRightItem
export default withStyles(navBar)(NavBar);


//NavBarRightItem.js
import React from 'react';

const NavBarRightItem = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      NavBarRightItem
    </div>
  )
}
NavBarRightItem.displayName = "NavBarRightItem";

export default NavBarRightItem;



//Product.js
import React from 'react';

import NavBar from '../components/Navigation/NavBar';

const Product = () => (
  <NavBar>
    <NavBar.Right />
  </NavBar>
);

export default Product;
```

`NavBar.Right` is undefined??
Thanks!

Comment: You assign it to `NavBar.NavBarRight` and try to access `NavBar.Right`? Never used a setup like this so sorry if that's ok, just looks odd to me.

Comment: @TobiasK. Thanks mate! Late night coding is evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your code `NavBar.Right` should be `undefined`, the one that is defined is `NavBar.NavBarRight`